# why complex manifolds of general type have no global holomorphic vector fields?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

If $X$ is a complex manifold of general type, why does it not have global non-trivial holomorphic vector fields? By "general type" I mean the property that Kodaira dimension equals complex dimension.

More generally, since I am not sure if the question is necessarily of analytic nature, is it true that $H^0(X, T_X)=0$ for a smooth algebraic variety $X$ of general type over a field?

Comment: You can always integrate a holomorphic vector field resulting in infinite group of biholomorphic automorphisms which contradicts the general type assumption.

Comment: In finite characteristic there is a counter example https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119460/automorphism-groups-of-general-type-varieties.

Comment: @MoisheCohen: the only proof of finiteness of the group of automorphisms of a manifold of general type I know refers to non-existence of a global holomorphic vector field. Is there another, "self-contained", argument?

Comment: Kobayashi, "Transformation Groups in Differential Geometry", page 88. Although this was proven earlier by Matsumura. There are other proofs for instance by Wang, 1977,  using measure hyperbolic of manifolds of general type..

Comment: @MoisheCohen: oh, some more searching and asking around gave the following easy observation. Assume $K_X$ is ample. Then by Serre duality $H^0(X, T_X) \cong H^n(X,T_X^{\vee}, \otimes K_X)^{\vee}$ where the latter group vanishes by Kodaira vanishing theorem. No need to recourse to finiteness of automorpism groups (and actually we can now deduce this from this observation)

Comment: I suspected there is an easy argument along these lines. But finiteness of the automorphism group is stronger since this group might be, a priory, discrete.

Comment: if the variety is projective, it must embed in $\mathbb{P}^n$, I think.

Comment: I am not sure about finite generatedness though

Comment: Oh, you are right, and use Kodaira's embedding to guarantee extension of automorphisms to the projective space. This is probably Matsumura's argument.

Comment: why Kodaira embedding? it is true as $K_X \cong f^* K_X$

Comment: You cannot use some random embedding, but use instead one given by sections of a very ample *natural* bundle, so that automorphisms act.

Comment: oh, right, $K_X$ is only ample. But then I am confused, which natural bundle do you have in mind?

Comment: Take a sufficiently high power of the canonical bundle. As for finite generation, it is due to Serre it Kodaira, I forgot. It should be covered in Griffiths and Harris.

Comment: Please do not ask questions only in the title.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: I have added the question to the body of.. the question

Comment: @DimaSustretov: Are you sure $T^*_X$ satisfies the assumption of the vanishing theorem?

Comment: @ChrisHuang yes, Kodaira(-Akizuki-Nakano) vanishing says that $H^q(X, L \otimes \Omega_X^p) = 0$ for $L$ ample and $p + q > \mathrm{dim}\,X$, in the case above $q=\mathrm{dim}\,X$ and $p=1$

Comment: @DimaSustretov I see, so you're applying the Kodaira-Nakano vanishing theorem. Thank you for the quick response